# jquery find previous li and change css

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I'm trying to write up a script that will allow me to change the css of the previous li on hover.

Here's the structure:

```
<ul id="mainlevel">
  <li><a href="/" class="mainlevel" id="active_menu">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="mainlevel">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="mainlevel">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="mainlevel">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="mainlevel">Suppliers</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
jQuery("#mainlevel li a").hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).prev("li a").css("background", "#f0f");
  });
```

But it's not working.. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Without testing anything, have you tried removing the `a` from the `.prev('li a')`?

Comment: yep, I'm having no luck with it

Comment: Do you want to manipulate the li that was previously hovered, or the li that precedes the hovered element in the document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('li a').hover(
      function(){
       $(this).parent().prev('li').css('background-color','#f0f'); 
      }
      );
  }
  );
```

Albeit I haven't removed the background-colours when the `li` is no longer hovered-over.

Demo at: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ijoju3).

Comment: @SoulieBaby, having posted this answer, it occurs to me to ask: are you sure you want to change the background of the `li`, and *not* the background of the child `a` element?

Comment: Oh it was to change the a, but I used what you had given me and added .find("a") to it to get it to work for me, thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this

```
jQuery(this).parent().prev("li").children("a").css("background", "#f0f");
```

I think the prev() methods works with only the siblings of the current element. that is why you have to get the parent of the current element and then get the prev element